# Color Changing Background

Tags: javascript, html, css

As its soon December, I added a Christmas background script into my time changing blue background that will set the background to a Christmas picture throughout December (Day and Night) and when its any other month it will go back to time changing colour

I have done something wrong because my code produces a white background, here are my scripts:
[**JSfiddle One that's not working**](http://Jsfiddle.net/q1ozpc7d/)
[**JSfiddle Working background without Christmas effects**](http://Jsfiddle.net/Samdenty99/qpf5vybp/)

**The One thats not working:**

```
<body>
<style>
.one {
    -webkit-animation: one 2s 1;
    -moz-animation: one 2s 1;
    -o-animation: one 2s 1;
    animation: one 2s 1;
    background-color: #280197;
}
.two {
    -webkit-animation: two 2s 1;
    -moz-animation: two 2s 1;
    -o-animation: two 2s 1;
    animation: two 2s 1;
    background-color: #501CE3;
}
.three {
    -webkit-animation: three 2s 1;
    -moz-animation: three 2s 1;
    -o-animation: three 2s 1;
    animation: three 2s 1;
    background-color: #2882F1;
}
.four {
    -webkit-animation: four 2s 1;
    -moz-animation: four 2s 1;
    -o-animation: four 2s 1;
    animation: four 2s 1;
    background-color: #519BF6;
}
.five {
    -webkit-animation: five 2s 1;
    -moz-animation: five 2s 1;
    -o-animation: five 2s 1;
    animation: five 2s 1;
    background-color: #69ABFC;
}
.six {
    -webkit-animation: six 2s 1;
    -moz-animation: six 2s 1;
    -o-animation: six 2s 1;
    animation: six 2s 1;
    background-color: #7BB5FD;
}
.seven {
    -webkit-animation: seven 2s 1;
    -moz-animation: seven 2s 1;
    -o-animation: seven 2s 1;
    animation: seven 2s 1;
    background-color: #AFD2FE;
}
.eight {
    -webkit-animation: eight 2s 1;
    -moz-animation: eight 2s 1;
    -o-animation: eight 2s 1;
    animation: eight 2s 1;
    background-color: #AFD2FE;
}
.nine {
    -webkit-animation: nine 2s 1;
    -moz-animation: nine 2s 1;
    -o-animation: nine 2s 1;
    animation: nine 2s 1;
    background-color: #9DCBFB;
}
.ten {
    -webkit-animation: ten 2s 1;
    -moz-animation: ten 2s 1;
    -o-animation: ten 2s 1;
    animation: ten 2s 1;
    background-color: #9DCBFB;
}
.eleven {
    -webkit-animation: eleven 2s 1;
    -moz-animation: eleven 2s 1;
    -o-animation: eleven 2s 1;
    animation: eleven 2s 1;
    background-color: #74B1FE;
}
.twelve {
    -webkit-animation: twelve 2s 1;
    -moz-animation: twelve 2s 1;
    -o-animation: twelve 2s 1;
    animation: twelve 2s 1;
    background-color: #4899FC;
}
.thirteen {
    -webkit-animation: thirteen 2s 1;
    -moz-animation: thirteen 2s 1;
    -o-animation: thirteen 2s 1;
    animation: thirteen 2s 1;
    background-color: #4899FC;
}
.fourteen {
    -webkit-animation: fourteen 2s 1;
    -moz-animation: fourteen 2s 1;
    -o-animation: fourteen 2s 1;
    animation: fourteen 2s 1;
    background-color: #0E75F4;
}
.fifteen {
    -webkit-animation: fifteen 2s 1;
    -moz-animation: fifteen 2s 1;
    -o-animation: fifteen 2s 1;
    animation: fifteen 2s 1;
    background-color: #0161D8;
}
.sixteen {
    -webkit-animation: sixteen 2s 1;
    -moz-animation: sixteen 2s 1;
    -o-animation: sixteen 2s 1;
    animation: sixteen 2s 1;
    background-color: #3904CF;
}
.seventeen {
    -webkit-animation: seventeen 2s 1;
    -moz-animation: seventeen 2s 1;
    -o-animation: seventeen 2s 1;
    animation: seventeen 2s 1;
    background-color: #3404BE;
}
.eighteen {
    -webkit-animation: eighteen 2s 1;
    -moz-animation: eighteen 2s 1;
    -o-animation: eighteen 2s 1;
    animation: eighteen 2s 1;
    background-color: #2F02B1;
}
.nineteen {
    -webkit-animation: nineteen 2s 1;
    -moz-animation: nineteen 2s 1;
    -o-animation: nineteen 2s 1;
    animation: nineteen 2s 1;
    background-color: #240385;
}
.twenty {
    -webkit-animation: twenty 2s 1;
    -moz-animation: twenty 2s 1;
    -o-animation: twenty 2s 1;
    animation: twenty 2s 1;
    background-color: #1A025E;
}
.twentyone {
    -webkit-animation: twentyone 2s 1;
    -moz-animation: twentyone 2s 1;
    -o-animation: twentyone 2s 1;
    animation: twentyone 2s 1;
    background-color: #000000;
}




@-moz-keyframes one {
    from {
        background-color: black;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #280197;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes two {
    from {
        background-color: #280197;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #501CE3;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes three {
    from {
        background-color: #501CE3;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #2882F1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes four {
    from {
        background-color: #2882F1;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #519BF6;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes five {
    from {
        background-color: #519BF6;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #69ABFC;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes six {
    from {
        background-color: #69ABFC;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #7BB5FD;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes seven {
    from {
        background-color: #7BB5FD;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #AFD2FE;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes eight {
    from {
        background-color: #AFD2FE;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #AFD2FE;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes nine {
    from {
        background-color: #AFD2FE;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #9DCBFB;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes ten {
    from {
        background-color: #9DCBFB;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #9DCBFB;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes eleven {
    from {
        background-color: #9DCBFB;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #74B1FE;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes twelve {
    from {
        background-color: #74B1FE;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #4899FC;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes thirteen {
    from {
        background-color: #4899FC;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #4899FC;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fourteen {
    from {
        background-color: #4899FC;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #0E75F4;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fifteen {
    from {
        background-color: #0E75F4;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #0161D8;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes sixteen {
    from {
        background-color: #0161D8;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #3904CF;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes seventeen {
    from {
        background-color: #3904CF;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #3404BE;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes eighteen {
    from {
        background-color: #3404BE;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #2F02B1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes nineteen {
    from {
        background-color: #2F02B1;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #240385;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes twenty {
    from {
        background-color: #240385;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #1A025E;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes twentyone {
    from {
        background-color: #1A025E;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #000000;
    }
}





@-webkit-keyframes one {
    from {
        background-color: black;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #280197;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes two {
    from {
        background-color: #280197;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #501CE3;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes three {
    from {
        background-color: #501CE3;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #2882F1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes four {
    from {
        background-color: #2882F1;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #519BF6;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes five {
    from {
        background-color: #519BF6;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #69ABFC;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes six {
    from {
        background-color: #69ABFC;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #7BB5FD;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes seven {
    from {
        background-color: #7BB5FD;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #AFD2FE;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes eight {
    from {
        background-color: #AFD2FE;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #AFD2FE;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes nine {
    from {
        background-color: #AFD2FE;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #9DCBFB;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes ten {
    from {
        background-color: #9DCBFB;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #9DCBFB;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes eleven {
    from {
        background-color: #9DCBFB;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #74B1FE;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes twelve {
    from {
        background-color: #74B1FE;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #4899FC;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes thirteen {
    from {
        background-color: #4899FC;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #4899FC;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fourteen {
    from {
        background-color: #4899FC;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #0E75F4;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fifteen {
    from {
        background-color: #0E75F4;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #0161D8;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes sixteen {
    from {
        background-color: #0161D8;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #3904CF;
    }
@-webkit-keyframes seventeen {
    from {
        background-color: #3904CF;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #3404BE;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes eighteen {
    from {
        background-color: #3404BE;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #2F02B1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes nineteen {
    from {
        background-color: #2F02B1;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #240385;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes twenty {
    from {
        background-color: #240385;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #1A025E;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes twentyone {
    from {
        background-color: #1A025E;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #000000;
    }
}
.christmas {
    -webkit-animation: christmas 4s 1;
    -moz-animation: christmas 4s 1;
    -o-animation: christmas 4s 1;
    animation: christmas 4s 1;
    background-image: url("christmas.png");
    background-color: #CD0404;
}
@-webkit-keyframes christmas {
    from {
        background-color: #FBB0B0;
    }
    to {
    background-image: url("christmas.png");
    background-color: #CD0404;
    background-size: cover;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes christmas {
    from {
        background-color: #FBB0B0;
    }
    to {
    background-image: url("christmas.png");
    background-color: #CD0404;
    background-size: cover;
    }
}
</style>


<script>
var b = document.body;

setInterval(function () {
    var time = new Date().getHours();
    var month = d.getMonth();
    var lst = b.classList;

    if (month >= 11 && month <= 0) {        // If the time is past December but before January
        lst.add('christmas')

    } else if (time >= 0 && time <= 5) {   // If the time is past 12 O'Clock (N) but before 5 O'Clock (Morning)
        if (lst.contains('twenty')) {lst.remove('twenty')};
        lst.add('one')
    } else if (time > 5 && time <= 6) {    // If the time is past 5 O'Clock (M) but before 6 O'Clock (Morning)
        if (lst.contains('one')) {lst.remove('one')};
        lst.add('two')
    } else if (time > 6 && time <= 7) {   // If the time is past 6 O'Clock (M) but before 7 O'Clock (Morning)
        if (lst.contains('two')) {lst.remove('two')};
        lst.add('three')
    } else if (time > 7 && time <= 8) {   // If the time is past 7 O'Clock (M) but before 8 O'Clock (Morning)
        if (lst.contains('three')) {lst.remove('three')};
        lst.add('four')
    } else if (time > 8 && time <= 9) {   // If the time is past 8 O'Clock (M) but before 9 O'Clock (Morning)
        if (lst.contains('four')) {lst.remove('four')};
        lst.add('five')
    } else if (time > 9 && time <= 10) {  // If the time is past 9 O'Clock (M) but before 10 O'Clock (Morning)
        if (lst.contains('five')) {lst.remove('five')};
        lst.add('six')
    } else if (time > 10 && time <= 11) { // If the time is past 10 O'Clock (M) but before 11 O'Clock (Morning)
        if (lst.contains('six')) {lst.remove('six')};
        lst.add('seven')
    } else if (time > 11 && time <= 12) { // If the time is past 11 O'Clock (M) but before 12 O'Clock (Morning)
        if (lst.contains('seven')) {lst.remove('seven')};    //*
        lst.add('eight')
    } else if (time > 12 && time <= 13) {   // If the time is past 12 O'Clock (M) but before 1 O'Clock (Night)
        if (lst.contains('eight')) {lst.remove('eight')};
        lst.add('nine')
    } else if (time > 13 && time <= 14) {   // If the time is past 1 O'Clock (N) but before 2 O'Clock (Night)
        if (lst.contains('nine')) {lst.remove('nine')};
        lst.add('ten')
    } else if (time > 14 && time <= 15) {   // If the time is past 2 O'Clock (N) but before 3 O'Clock (Night)
        if (lst.contains('ten')) {lst.remove('ten')};
        lst.add('eleven')
    } else if (time > 15 && time <= 16) {   // If the time is past 3 O'Clock (N) but before 4 O'Clock (Night)
        if (lst.contains('eleven')) {lst.remove('eleven')};
        lst.add('twelve')
    } else if (time > 16 && time <= 17) {   // If the time is past 4 O'Clock (N) but before 5 O'Clock (Night)
        if (lst.contains('twelve')) {lst.remove('twelve')};
        lst.add('thirteen')
    } else if (time > 17 && time <= 18) {   // If the time is past 5 O'Clock (N) but before 6 O'Clock (Night)
        if (lst.contains('thirteen')) {lst.remove('thirteen')};
        lst.add('fourteen')
    } else if (time > 18 && time <= 19) {   // If the time is past 6 O'Clock (N) but before 7 O'Clock (Night)*
        if (lst.contains('fourteen')) {lst.remove('fourteen')};
        lst.add('fifteen')
    } else if (time > 19 && time <= 20) {   // If the time is past 7 O'Clock (N) but before 8 O'Clock (Night)
        if (lst.contains('fifteen')) {lst.remove('fifteen')};
        lst.add('sixteen')
    } else if (time > 20 && time <= 21) {   // If the time is past 8 O'Clock (N) but before 9 O'Clock (Night)
        if (lst.contains('sixteen')) {lst.remove('sixteen')};
        lst.add('seventeen')
    } else if (time > 21 && time <= 22) {   // If the time is past 9 O'Clock (N) but before 10 O'Clock (Night)
        if (lst.contains('seventeen')) {lst.remove('seventeen')};
        lst.add('eighteen')
    } else if (time > 22 && time <= 23) {   // If the time is past 10 O'Clock (N) but before 11 O'Clock (Night)
        if (lst.contains('eighteen')) {lst.remove('eighteen')};
        lst.add('nineteen')
    } else if (time > 23 && time <= 24) {   // If the time is past 11 O'Clock (N) but before 12 O'Clock (Night)
        if (lst.contains('nineteen')) {lst.remove('nineteen')};
        lst.add('twenty')
    } else if (time > 24 && time <= 1) {   // If the time is past 12 O'Clock (N) but before 1 O'Clock (Morning)*
        if (lst.contains('twenty')) {lst.remove('twenty')};
        lst.add('twentyone')
    }

}, 1000);
</script>
<script>
  var month = d.getMonth();

</script>
```

Comment: You can't animate background images. Also, `cover` isn't an animateble value for `background-size`. Check the spec: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED ANSWER:

If you can choose 11. and 12. month, `if (month >= 11)` is enough. You cannot see now if your code like this, because we are not December now.

If you want to check your code, you can put this code: `if (month >= 9)` Its work.

Also, your month variable was undefined and working version is here:

Updated:
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q1ozpc7d/4/)**

Comment: I know, because i want to have the Christmas effects, the 'working' version was the version i was previously using (before i decided to  use the christmas background) and the 'Not working ' version is the one that should have the christmas background, but not working

Comment: This is such a pain in the a**, I changed the background.png in the css to [External Image](http://sd-storage.weebly.com/files/theme/christmas.png) and it isnt working :( [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Samdenty99/q1ozpc7d/5/)

Comment: Add .christmas class in CSS file and add background. See it: jsfiddle.net/q1ozpc7d/4

Answer (score 0):

`d` is not defined in your function (see code snippet), so I think this fixes it for you ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q1ozpc7d/1/))

```
setInterval(function () {
    var time = new Date().getHours();
    // var month = d.getMonth();    d is not defined!
    var month = new Date().getMonth();
    var lst = b.classList;

    if (month >= 11 && month <= 0) {        // If the time is past December but before January
        lst.add('christmas')
```

Note that it is also logically impossible to be greater than 11 AND less than 0

Comment: @Simon_H That code doesnt work, I put that into it and changed 11 to 10 (current month) and it still goes blue, So what should i put instead of     (month >= 11 && month <= 0)

Comment: @Simon_H If greater than 11 AND less than 0' means in JavaScript months 'If greater than December and less than January' Doesnt It?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code (With added snowflakes):
[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9aus4j6k/)

```
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://sd-storage.weebly.com/files/theme/skycss.css">
<script>
var b = document.body;

setInterval(function () {
    var time = new Date().getHours();
    var month = new Date().getMonth();
    var lst = b.classList;

    if (month >= 11) {        // If the date is past December
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://sd-storage.weebly.com/files/theme/christmas.png')";
        document.body.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
        var snowsrc="http://sd-storage.weebly.com/files/theme/snow.gif"
        var no = 10;
        var hidesnowtime = 0;
        var snowdistance = "pageheight";
        var ie4up = (document.all) ? 1 : 0;
        var ns6up = (document.getElementById&&!document.all) ? 1 : 0;
        function iecompattest(){
        return (document.compatMode && document.compatMode!="BackCompat")? document.documentElement : document.body
        }
        var dx, xp, yp;
        var am, stx, sty;
        var i, doc_width = 800, doc_height = 600;
        if (ns6up) {
        doc_width = self.innerWidth;
        doc_height = self.innerHeight;
        } else if (ie4up) {
        doc_width = iecompattest().clientWidth;
        doc_height = iecompattest().clientHeight;
        }
        dx = new Array();
        xp = new Array();
        yp = new Array();
        am = new Array();
        stx = new Array();
        sty = new Array();
        snowsrc=(snowsrc.indexOf("http://sd-storage.weebly.com")!=-1)? "http://sd-storage.weebly.com/files/theme/snow.gif" : snowsrc
        for (i = 0; i < no; ++ i) {
        dx[i] = 0;
        xp[i] = Math.random()*(doc_width-50);
        yp[i] = Math.random()*doc_height;
        am[i] = Math.random()*20;
        stx[i] = 0.02 + Math.random()/10;
        sty[i] = 0.7 + Math.random();
        if (ie4up||ns6up) {
        if (i == 0) {
        document.write("<div id=\"dot"+ i +"\" style=\"POSITION: absolute; Z-INDEX: "+ i +"; VISIBILITY: visible; TOP: 15px; LEFT: 15px;\"><img src='"+snowsrc+"' border=\"0\"><\/a><\/div>");
        } else {
        document.write("<div id=\"dot"+ i +"\" style=\"POSITION: absolute; Z-INDEX: "+ i +"; VISIBILITY: visible; TOP: 15px; LEFT: 15px;\"><img src='"+snowsrc+"' border=\"0\"><\/div>");
        }
        }
        }
        function snowIE_NS6() {  // IE and NS6 main animation function
        doc_width = ns6up?window.innerWidth-10 : iecompattest().clientWidth-10;
        doc_height=(window.innerHeight && snowdistance=="windowheight")? window.innerHeight : (ie4up && snowdistance=="windowheight")?  iecompattest().clientHeight : (ie4up && !window.opera && snowdistance=="pageheight")? iecompattest().scrollHeight : iecompattest().offsetHeight;
        for (i = 0; i < no; ++ i) {  // iterate for every dot
        yp[i] += sty[i];
        if (yp[i] > doc_height-50) {
        xp[i] = Math.random()*(doc_width-am[i]-30);
        yp[i] = 0;
        stx[i] = 0.02 + Math.random()/10;
        sty[i] = 0.7 + Math.random();
        }
        dx[i] += stx[i];
        document.getElementById("dot"+i).style.top=yp[i]+"px";
        document.getElementById("dot"+i).style.left=xp[i] + am[i]*Math.sin(dx[i])+"px";
        }
        snowtimer=setTimeout("snowIE_NS6()", 10);
        }
        function hidesnow(){
        if (window.snowtimer) clearTimeout(snowtimer)
        for (i=0; i<no; i++) document.getElementById("dot"+i).style.visibility="hidden"
        }
        if (ie4up||ns6up){
        snowIE_NS6();
        if (hidesnowtime>0)
        setTimeout("hidesnow()", hidesnowtime*1000)
        }


    } else if (time >= 0 && time <= 5) {   // If the time is past 12 O'Clock (N) but before 5 O'Clock (Morning)
        if (lst.contains('twenty')) {lst.remove('twenty')};
        lst.add('one')
    } else if (time > 5 && time <= 6) {    // If the time is past 5 O'Clock (M) but before 6 O'Clock (Morning)
        if (lst.contains('one')) {lst.remove('one')};
        lst.add('two')
    } else if (time > 6 && time <= 7) {   // If the time is past 6 O'Clock (M) but before 7 O'Clock (Morning)
        if (lst.contains('two')) {lst.remove('two')};
        lst.add('three')
    } else if (time > 7 && time <= 8) {   // If the time is past 7 O'Clock (M) but before 8 O'Clock (Morning)
        if (lst.contains('three')) {lst.remove('three')};
        lst.add('four')
    } else if (time > 8 && time <= 9) {   // If the time is past 8 O'Clock (M) but before 9 O'Clock (Morning)
        if (lst.contains('four')) {lst.remove('four')};
        lst.add('five')
    } else if (time > 9 && time <= 10) {  // If the time is past 9 O'Clock (M) but before 10 O'Clock (Morning)
        if (lst.contains('five')) {lst.remove('five')};
        lst.add('six')
    } else if (time > 10 && time <= 11) { // If the time is past 10 O'Clock (M) but before 11 O'Clock (Morning)
        if (lst.contains('six')) {lst.remove('six')};
        lst.add('seven')
    } else if (time > 11 && time <= 12) { // If the time is past 11 O'Clock (M) but before 12 O'Clock (Morning)
        if (lst.contains('seven')) {lst.remove('seven')};    //*
        lst.add('eight')
    } else if (time > 12 && time <= 13) {   // If the time is past 12 O'Clock (M) but before 1 O'Clock (Night)
        if (lst.contains('eight')) {lst.remove('eight')};
        lst.add('nine')
    } else if (time > 13 && time <= 14) {   // If the time is past 1 O'Clock (N) but before 2 O'Clock (Night)
        if (lst.contains('nine')) {lst.remove('nine')};
        lst.add('ten')
    } else if (time > 14 && time <= 15) {   // If the time is past 2 O'Clock (N) but before 3 O'Clock (Night)
        if (lst.contains('ten')) {lst.remove('ten')};
        lst.add('eleven')
    } else if (time > 15 && time <= 16) {   // If the time is past 3 O'Clock (N) but before 4 O'Clock (Night)
        if (lst.contains('eleven')) {lst.remove('eleven')};
        lst.add('twelve')
    } else if (time > 16 && time <= 17) {   // If the time is past 4 O'Clock (N) but before 5 O'Clock (Night)
        if (lst.contains('twelve')) {lst.remove('twelve')};
        lst.add('thirteen')
    } else if (time > 17 && time <= 18) {   // If the time is past 5 O'Clock (N) but before 6 O'Clock (Night)
        if (lst.contains('thirteen')) {lst.remove('thirteen')};
        lst.add('fourteen')
    } else if (time > 18 && time <= 19) {   // If the time is past 6 O'Clock (N) but before 7 O'Clock (Night)*
        if (lst.contains('fourteen')) {lst.remove('fourteen')};
        lst.add('fifteen')
    } else if (time > 19 && time <= 20) {   // If the time is past 7 O'Clock (N) but before 8 O'Clock (Night)
        if (lst.contains('fifteen')) {lst.remove('fifteen')};
        lst.add('sixteen')
    } else if (time > 20 && time <= 21) {   // If the time is past 8 O'Clock (N) but before 9 O'Clock (Night)
        if (lst.contains('sixteen')) {lst.remove('sixteen')};
        lst.add('seventeen')
    } else if (time > 21 && time <= 22) {   // If the time is past 9 O'Clock (N) but before 10 O'Clock (Night)
        if (lst.contains('seventeen')) {lst.remove('seventeen')};
        lst.add('eighteen')
    } else if (time > 22 && time <= 23) {   // If the time is past 10 O'Clock (N) but before 11 O'Clock (Night)
        if (lst.contains('eighteen')) {lst.remove('eighteen')};
        lst.add('nineteen')
    } else if (time > 23 && time <= 24) {   // If the time is past 11 O'Clock (N) but before 12 O'Clock (Night)
        if (lst.contains('nineteen')) {lst.remove('nineteen')};
        lst.add('twenty')
    } else if (time > 24 && time <= 1) {   // If the time is past 12 O'Clock (N) but before 1 O'Clock (Morning)*
        if (lst.contains('twenty')) {lst.remove('twenty')};
        lst.add('twentyone')
    }

}, 1000);
</script>
```